# deploy java jax ws web service as stand alone server

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

i am new to webservice. i need your help to understand deployment process.

I have created a new webservice by using following tutorial

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-eclipse-javase1/section2.html

web service is running fine in eclipse,

right now i am running this service by right clicking on endpoint class and run it as java application. i want to run this service manually because on our server we not going to install eclipse.

Comment: Do you want to deploy this as a service in your server so that it can be accessed from anywhere?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "our server"... what kind of server are we talking about?

Comment: thanks for reply, yes i want to deploy this as a service on server so that it can be accessed from anywhere.
"our server" means web server where i am want to deploy this webservice

Comment: When i use eclipse to run webservice endpoint it is running on http://localhost:8089/searchServer, i have created client to send request to that url and get response form there and both service and client are working fine. now i want to deploy webservice without eclipse. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bundle your web service implementation classes as jar and you need to deploy to any Java EE complaint servers like JBoss or GlassFish.

Comment: In eclipse you can export them as Jar.

Comment: can you please send me steps how to bundle this classes, following is the structure of class files


/Falcon
/falcon/src
/faclon/src/com/dnb/discovery
/falcon/src/com/dnb/discovery/searchservice


searchservice package holds an implementation class and endpoint publish function

Comment: After i bundle a jar adn add it in jboss, it is accessible on using same url for now i am using http://localhost:8089/searchServer

Comment: Correct.  But you should observe, now you are not running in your development environment but in an application server.  In production you will do the same thing like you will have one application server and deploy your webservice jar in it.

Comment: i have created a jar file and added it in tomcats lib folder, when i start tomcat above url is not accesible for me it gives and error page not found. is there any thing that i am missing

Comment: You cant use tomcat for this.  You should use J2EE container.  Use either JBoss or Glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

You need some web site to host your application. Eclipse is hosting it for you on your local machine but to use manually I assume you mean you want it on a real site?

Comment: It is possible to host this application on local machine? also as i told i am new to this, so i don't know how to deploy it, Steps to deploy this service will be helpfull

Comment: Eclipse runs Tomcat or Glassfish which does the hosting for you. It would be a pain to try to do this manually.

Comment: ok can you please tell me how to deploy this in tomcat or jboss server? actually i found some tutorials on google but that is not usefull for me.

Comment: It sounds like you already have some sort of a web server running. It sounds like you need to find out the details of what you have running and add your app to it?

Comment: i have two server running on my local machine jboss and tomcat. i want to find a way to deploy my newly created webservice on that servers and access it from other client programs